# Formatting a time in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Elixir, trying to port a Rails API to Phoenix as a learning project.

I have a *Postgres time field*, which I've added to an *Ecto scheme*:

```
field :start_time, Ecto.Time
```

**Problem:** I'd like to output a 12-hour formatted version of a time such as 16:30 as a string: 4:30pm, for example. I have been having trouble finding an easy/standard way of doing this.

**This is the closest I've yet come to a solution:**

```
def format_time(time) do
  {:ok, {hours,minutes,y, z}} = Ecto.Time.dump(time)
  {hour, ampm} = Timex.Time.to_12hour_clock(hours)
  "#{hour}:#{minutes}#{ampm}"
end
```

This seems like a ridiculous and ridiculously long piece of code for something I imagine already has a more concise and standard implementation; in addition it has the problem of outputting 2:0pm instead of 2:00 pm – formatting the 0 with a trailing zero was additionally long and complicated piece of code that I was working on –– at which point I started feeling like things were going way off track.

Advice appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the formatting facilities of `timex` since you're already using that, but first you need to change your `Ecto.Time` into a `Timex.DateTime` that can be formatted with those.

```
use Timex

{{0, 0, 0}, Ecto.Time.to_erl(time)}
|> Timex.Date.from
|> DateFormat.format!("{h12}:{0m} {am}")
```

Comment: This is a cleaner version of the same solution I ended up with, so the minutes are still poorly formatted as 2:0pm rather than 2:30pm.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Pawel, this helped get me to a solution!

Comment: Oops, forgot about that. You need to use the `{0m}` format directive for minutes to pad with zeroes.

Comment: So the strftime version of DateFormat.format! that sevenseascat mentioned also worked great, but since this is a very complete answer, I'll will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Since Elixir 1.11 they now have a built-in formatter. `Calendar.strftime/3`
[documentation here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Calendar.html#strftime/3)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and using a library like `Timex`.
That's my way how to handle dates. I don't know if there better work cases.

- [Calendar](https://github.com/lau/calendar) for parsing and some functions.
- [Calecto](https://github.com/lau/calecto) for using
  `Calendar` with `Ecto`

In this case you can use [Calendar.Strftime](http://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.Strftime.html) for a formatted date/time string.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

You're using Timex, but not its `format!` method which allows for easy time and date formatting.

https://david.padilla.cc/posts/19-date-formatting-in-phoenix-elixir is a good write up on using Timex.

It looks like you might be able to do something like the following:

```
Timex.DateFormat.format!(time, "%H:%M%P", :strftime)
```

See https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/master/lib/format/datetime/formatters/strftime.ex for the full list of formatting options.

Comment: This does not work for me, I'm getting a no function clause matching in Timex.DateFormat.format!/3 – I think related to the fact that I have a time not a datetime?

Comment: Thanks for the advice sevenseacat –– this didn't get me there entirely but along with Pawel Obrok's advice it helped get me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

This is the workable solution that I arrived at, which was a combination of the answers from Pawel, Obrok, and sevenseascat – with the addition of getting the minutes into `00` format.

```
def formatted_time(time) do
  {{0, 0, 0}, Ecto.Time.to_erl(time)} |> 
  Timex.Date.from |> 
  DateFormat.format!("%I:%M%P", :strftime)
end
```

Comment: Good to hear it was resolved :) I wasn't sure of the exact conversion between an Ecto.Time and a Timex.Time, but I'm glad I could help regardless!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is to use `strftime` string formatting available in `Calendar`. Using `Calecto` you can even use the basic types such as `Ecto.Time` or `Ecto.DateTime`.
This can be piped directly to `Calendar`'s formatting, like so:

```
@ecto_struct.some_time |> Calendar.Strftime.strftime! "%I:%M%P"
```

Will result in:

```
"02:30pm"
```

All you have to do is add `Calecto` as a dependency:

```
defp deps do
  [ {:calecto, "~> 0.4.1"}, ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @lau saw your talk at ElixirConf and will make a point of checking out these libraries!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

starttimereadable =
NaiveDateTime.from_erl!({{2000, 1, 1}, Time.to_erl(starttime)})
|> Timex.format!("{h12}:{0m} {am}")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).